# Solve recurrence by generating functions

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

Find non-recurrent expression for the following sequence: $a_0=a_1=1\;\; 5a_{n+2}=4a_{n+1}-a_n$
The formula I got for the respective generating function:
$$5(A(x)-1-x)=4x(A(x)-1)-x^2A(x)$$
$$A(x)=\frac{x+5}{5-4x+x^2}$$
The denominator is irreducible, so I can't get further by partial fractions expansion.

Comment: You can still use partial fractions, as the denominator factors over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @Slade But that would yield an imaginary formula.

Comment: Is this a problem?  You can also use the binomial formula to write the answer as a sum of real values.

Comment: @Slade How could I use the binomial formula here?

Comment: First, find the answer in terms of complex numbers.  Then expand using the binomial formula.  Alternatively, you could use Euler's formula to express the answer in terms of trigonometric functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use complex numbers, you can start by completing the square, giving 
$$ x^2 - 4x + 5 = (x - 2)^2 + 1 $$
Hence 
\begin{align*}
  A(x) &= \frac{x+5}{(x-2)^2 + 1}\\
       &= (x+5) \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k(x-2)^{2k}\\
\end{align*}
Now expand using the binomial theorem.